# Кнопки соц.сетей от Яндекс сбоку

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Каким образом можно вывести кнопки сбоку в одну колонку, чтобы они плавали?

Answer (score 0):

Кнопки соц. сетей лучше писать самому, чтобы быть уверенным в том, что браузер вашего пользователя не накачает каких-либо лишних `js` скриптов, которые идут вместе с этими кнопками.

Жалобы разгневанных пользователей на то, что вы (а на самом деле, это даже не вы!!) собираете их конфиденциальную информацию, врядли помогут продвижению вашего сайта..